img src is in array of object, using async await but images do not appear in react app
const [decks, setDecks] = useState();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

function getCardImage(decks){
        decks.map(async(deck)=>{
            deck.img = await MagicApi.getCardImage(deck.commander);
        })
        return decks;
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        const gettingDecks = async (userInfo) => {
            const res = await UserApi.getDecks(userInfo);
            const res2 = await getCardImage(res);

            setDecks(res2);
            setLoading(false);
        }
        gettingDecks({id})
    },[]);

if(loading) return <div><h3>Fetching Your Commander Decks...</h3></div>
    
    console.log(decks)
        return(
        
            <Row>
                
                {decks.map(deck => {
                    return (
                    <Card key={crypto.randomUUID()}>
                            
                            <CardImg
                                alt="Card image cap"
                                src={deck.img}
                                style={{height: 300}}
                                top
                                width="50%"/>

                            <CardTitle><h3>{deck.commander}</h3></CardTitle>
                            
                            <CardBody>
                                <p>{deck.colors}</p>
                            </CardBody>
                            
                            <Button onClick={() => deleteDeck(deck)}>Delete</Button>
                        
                    </Card>
                    )
                })}
                
            </Row>
        )

when i look at the components in the dev tools it says my img src is undefined. but when i console.log before my return it shows the img url from the api.
been trying to google for a while and just cant find anything. I want the images to be shown on render.
Thank you in advance for any help!

You are not waiting for any of the promises returned by decks.map(...) (Promise.all could be used to wait for all of them) and you are also discarding the result (Array#map creates a new array without affecting the original).
You could use a for...of loop instead (which may be easier to understand):
const gettingDecks = async (userInfo) => {
    const decks = await UserApi.getDecks(userInfo);
    for (const deck of decks)
        deck.img = await MagicApi.getCardImage(deck.commander);
    setDecks(decks);
    setLoading(false);
}

Or with Promise.all:
const gettingDecks = async (userInfo) => {
    const decks = await UserApi.getDecks(userInfo);
    await Promise.all(decks.map(async deck => 
        deck.img = await MagicApi.getCardImage(deck.commander)));
    setDecks(decks);
    setLoading(false);
}


for...of will be slower though, since you're processing one at a time, rather than as many parallel as other constraints allow

@JaromandaX Fair enough; I've added the Promise.all version.

Thank you so much that worked perfectly!!!

@GrantBollaert Happy to help.
